# oracle pl/sql collection varray

Tags: oracle, plsql

I read a book about oracle pl/SQL. and in the book there is a section which is about how to use the collection, it has some code to introduce varray. and I typed it in my toad the same like the book, but when I compiled it, in line 16 it told me that "column not allowed here." so I am not sure what happened, can anyone help me, please?

```
create type first_name_t is varray (2) of varchar2(100);
create type child_name_t is varray (1) of varchar2(100);

create table family 
(
  surname varchar2(1000),
  parent_names first_name_t,
  children_name child_name_t
);

declare
 childen child_name_t := child_name_t ();
 parents first_name_t := first_name_t ();

begin
 parents.extend (2);
 parents (1) := 'abc';
 parents (2) := 'elssads';

 childen.extend ;
 childen(1) := 'fea';


 insert into family(surname, parent_names, childen_name )
            values ('Assurty', parents, children);
end;
```

Comment: Watch the typos: declare variable `childen` but `children` in values clause; also column name is `children_name` and you insert into `childen_name`

Comment: Oracle hurls `ORA-00984: column not allowed here` when there's something in the `values (...)` clause which is neither a literal nor a named variable. In this case it's because you've got a typo in your code. Programming is all about the details. Compilers are super fussy about spelling and grammar, so we must learn to read what *we actually typed*, rather than what we think we typed.

Comment: Thanks I got it@husqvik

Comment: Now I get the meaning of what this sentence wants to tell me. thanks a lot!@apc

Answer (score 1):

Try this insert statement

```
insert into family values ('Assurty', parents,childen);
```